# Reactive helper input value behaviour in dynamic blaze templates

Tags: meteor

I am using a helper for getting a reactive variable into a dynamic template:

```
<template name='integer_element'>
{{#with data}}
    <div class='css_integer_element_wrapper'>
        <input class='css_integer_input js_input_element' value='{{this.value}}'>
    </div>
{{/with}}
```

when data and accordingly this.value changes the display value in the input element is supposed to change.
For some reason this does not work when the initial value is an empty string.

If the initial value is lets say 123 and i manually change the input to 124 then on data change the new value gets displayed and 124 is being discarded but when the initial default value is empty string and i change it to 124 then after data change the input element still displays 124.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Please, show the code for `data` helper and the part where you're initializing your reactive variable.

Comment: Also that's not a dynamic template, just a regular blaze template.

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer here to clarify the question, add more code and because it is too much text for a comment.

I am using dynamic templates to present data dependent on datatype. I require an input element in order to give the user the possibility to edit the default values (which come from the backend). As soon as the user modifies the input element the DOM takes over and then the particular input does not get reset upon reloading the template if it doesnt get destroyed. I have built a workaround with the 'if data available' flag but it is not very convenient and just there so I can make sure the template gets destroyed and rerendered. Is there a better way to rerender a specific template?

```
<body>
{{> form}}
</body>
<template name="form">
    {{#with data}}  
        {{#if data_available}}
        {{#each this.rows}}
             <div class="css_form_wrapper">
                {{>Template.dynamic template=this.template data= this}}
             </div>
        {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
        {{#unless data_available}}
            <div>
                Loading Data
            </div>
        {{/unless}}

        <div>
            <button class='button'>Refresh</button>
        </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>

<template name='element'>
    {{#with data}}
        <div class='element_wrapper'>
            <input class='css_element js_element' value='{{this.value}}'>
        </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

here is the js to it:

```
var form_tracker = new Tracker.Dependency;
var backend_tracker = new Tracker.Dependency;
var data_available = true;

Template.form.helpers({
  data: function () {
    var data  = _readData();
    return data;
  },
  data_available: function () {
    return data_available
  }
});

Template.form.events({
  'click .button':function(){
    data_available = false;
    _readBackendData();
    form_tracker.changed();
  }
});

var _readData = function () {
  form_tracker.depend();
  backend_tracker.depend();
  if(backend_tracker.data != undefined) {
    return backend_tracker.data
  } else {
    return {rows: [{'template': 'element', 'value' : 'no data initially'}]};
  }
};

var _readBackendData = function () {
  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    backend_tracker.data = {rows: [{'template': 'element', 'value' : 123}, {'template': 'element', 'value' : ''}]};
    backend_tracker.changed();
    data_available = true;
  }, 800);};

Template.element.helpers({
  data: function () {
    var data  = this;
    return data;
  }
});
```

You can test the different behaviour by taking out the 'if data_available' condition in the HTML. With condition the template gets destroyed and any input in the element gets overriden, without the condition the current value in the input element remains.